# Hive Import : java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.facebook.fb303.FacebookService$Client

Tags: java, hive, amazon-emr

I am using EMR 6.1.0 . I am trying to do hive import and it.

Caused by:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.facebook.fb303.FacebookService$Client.sendBaseOneway(Ljava/lang/String;Lorg/apache/thrift/TBase;)V
        at com.facebook.fb303.FacebookService$Client.send_shutdown(FacebookService.java:436)
        at com.facebook.fb303.FacebookService$Client.shutdown(FacebookService.java:430)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient.close(HiveMetaStoreClient.java:591)
```

PS: I have already added         permission javax.management.MBeanTrustPermission "register";
in java.policy but still there is the issue.

Comment: Had you already taken a look what "NosSuchMethodException" means? It is often the case that one or more dependencies is used in wrong version.

Comment: I am having libfb303-0.9.3.jar and libthrift-0.9.3.jar, There was another version libthrift-0.13.0.jar under spark jar folder but i moved  0.9.3 version to spark/jar also.. Even after that it was not working

Comment: Properbly  libfb303-0.9.3.jar is not compatible with libthrift-0.13.0.jar and within "libthrift-0.13.0.jar" is a different version. Have a look at https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Support-Questions/Exception-noSuchMethodError-trying-to-run-ML-examples-in/td-p/192045 and associate the hints to your project